# NVIDIA Hotkey Not Working Automatically At System Startup

Tags: nvidia-settings

I am using the NVIDIA hotkey `Control` when dragging a window, to let it snap to the desktop raster, defined via *NVIDIA RTX Desktop Manager*. In the desktop raster settings window, there is the option of using the `Control` hotkey when dragging a window. It is enabled.

This hotkey is not working after system startup though. Interestingly it starts working after opening the *NVIDIA Settings* window that can be launched with double click on its system tray icon. This icon is always there after system startup.

There is no system tray icon for *NVIDIA RTX Desktop Manager*. There is no autostart setting in the desktop manager. It wouldn't be the best way to launch the desktop manager window via autostart at every logon - it isn't needed for daily work. I will try this nevertheless, but I hope that there is a better solution.

---

Update: launching the NVIDIA Desktop Manager via autostart works

I have to close this window now after every login, so if there is a better solution...